# How to fix my scrollview is not scrolling correctly Android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have problems with my `scrollview` with my app and i don't know what could be the problem, the scroll doesn't show the things that are in the top of the layout and instead is showing a blank space in the bottom

I've tried using the scroll view as the father view , i've tried to put it inside a constraint layout but nothing of this solve the problem.

This is my layout which is a fragment. Actually it contains 13 elements in the menu, of course i didn't paste all of the items , just one.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".MenuFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardViewMenuPerfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewMenuPerfil"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_perfil_imagen"
                    app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
                    app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewMenuPerfilNombre"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/vacio"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Jorge Hernandez Nunez" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonMenuMisAnimales"
            style="@style/buttonMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mis_animales"
            android:text="@string/title_mis_animales" />

        <View style="@style/dividerComplete" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the activity that contains my fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenedor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how it should looks like https://ibb.co/QQDTz6n , in big screens there isn't a problem, the problem is in small screen because
it doesn't show up the the part of the profile: https://ibb.co/D8NL7kH
and also show a blank space https://ibb.co/vJWmTHN

Comment: which view is the blue toolbar?

Comment: your are putting to much code in your xml file , you should use recycler view instead

Comment: try remove this  android:scrollbars="none"

Comment: try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView`

Comment: the toolbar is always shown in the app , the first screenshot i cut it , it was my error , , I thought about using a recyclerview but I'm not sure if it is the best idea , I tried also scrollbar none and fillviewport and the error is still there